Should underwater materials have lower roughness values?
I'm make an island scene in Blender. The islands are small and they have a sand texture.
I was wondering about sand that's underwater. Would it be more physically correct to leave the texture roughness the same for sand that's under the water or to lower it?
Something like what you would do if you wanted to make a material look wet.

maybe change the Roughness but you need to also change its color, the wet sand is darker

Oh right, I forgot about base color.
But my question still remains... I know you should do this for materials out in the open that you want to make look wet, but what about materials that are actually underwater; so if you have a water layer on top of them. Should the same rule apply then?
